# How does tf.multinomial work?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, probability-theory

How does `tf.multinomial` work? [Here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/multinomial) is stated that it "Draws samples from a multinomial distribution". What does that mean?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you perform an experiment `n` times that can have only **two outcomes** (either success or failure, head or tail, etc.), then the number of times you obtain one of the two outcomes (success) is a ***binomial random variable***.

In other words, If you perform an experiment that can have only **two outcomes** (either success or failure, head or tail, etc.), then a random variable that takes value 1 in case of success and value 0 in case of failure is a **Bernoulli random variable**.

---

If you perform an experiment `n` times that can have `K` outcomes (where `K` can be any natural number) and you denote by  `X_i` the number of times that you obtain the  i-th outcome, then the random vector **`X`** defined as

> **X** = [X_1, X_2, X_3, ..., X_K]

is a multinomial random vector.

In other words, if you perform an experiment that can have `K` outcomes and you denote by  `X_i` a random variable that takes value 1 if you obtain the  i-th outcome and 0 otherwise, then the random vector  X defined as

> **X** = [X_1, X_2, X_3, ..., X_K]

is a Multinoulli random vector. In other words, when the  i-th outcome is obtained, the  i-th entry of the Multinoulli random vector `X` takes value  1, while all other entries take value 0.

So, a ***multinomial distribution*** can be seen as a sum of mutually independent Multinoulli random variables.

And the probabilities of the `K` possible outcomes will be denoted by

> p_1, p_2, p_3, ..., p_K

---

An example in Tensorflow,

```
In [171]: isess = tf.InteractiveSession()

In [172]: prob = [[.1, .2, .7], [.3, .3, .4]]  # Shape [2, 3]
     ...: dist = tf.distributions.Multinomial(total_count=[4., 5], probs=prob)
     ...: 
     ...: counts = [[2., 1, 1], [3, 1, 1]]
     ...: isess.run(dist.prob(counts))  # Shape [2]
     ...: 
Out[172]: array([ 0.0168    ,  0.06479999], dtype=float32)
```

Note: The Multinomial is identical to the
Binomial distribution when `K = 2`. For more detailed information please refer either [`tf.compat.v1.distributions.Multinomial`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/distributions/Multinomial) or the latest docs of [`tensorflow_probability.distributions.Multinomial`](https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/api_docs/python/tfp/distributions/Multinomial)

Comment: warning - no gradients

Comment: The docs have updated since the original post.  I think this might be the current link (though it is for `tfp` instead of `tf`): https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/api_docs/python/tfp/distributions/Multinomial

Comment: @StevenC.Howell grazie! Updated the link.